# yuv420p pixel format in GStreamer?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to stream a video from opencv/python to rtsp-simple-server via GStreamer. I am able to view the video fine in vlc, but the online streaming application I am using is very picky. I need the stream to have a pixel format of **`yuv420p`**. How do I convert a stream to this format with GStreamer?

This is my current code which creates a stream with the yuv444p:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert' + \
' ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast bitrate=600 key-int-max=40' + \
' ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:554/video',
cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, fps, (width, height), True)
```

I am looking for the GStreamer equivalent of `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.. videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! x264enc ..
```

You could also tell `x264` to use a specific profile that does 420 instead:

```
.. x264enc ! video/x-h264, profile=main ! ..
```

Both methods should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally worked. For future reference: I420 in GStreamer is the same as yuv420p in ffmpeg. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/mediatype-video-raw.html?gi-language=c#formats